# kms activation fails with office 2013

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, software-activation, volume-license

I've been trying to activate my office 2013 via my kms server manually and I get:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15>cscript OSPP.VBS /act

Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


---Processing--------------------------

---------------------------------------

Installed product key detected - attempting to activate the following product:

SKU ID: b322da9c-a2e2-4058-9e4e-f59a6970bd69

LICENSE NAME: Office 15, OfficeProPlusVL_KMS_Client edition

LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 15, VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel

Last 5 characters of installed product key: GVGXT

ERROR CODE: 0x80070005

ERROR DESCRIPTION: Run the following: cscript ospp.vbs /ddescr:0x80070005

NOTICE: A KB article has been detected for activation failure: 0x80070005

FOR MORE INFORMATION PLEASE VISIT: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2870357#Error0x80070005

---------------------------------------

---------------------------------------

---Exiting-----------------------------
```

I tried to follow:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-error-code-0x80070005-when-activating-office-7aa7600f-df57-4aef-81d2-25509c66f865
No change, ( I did get an error that a sub child wasn't able to change)
Does anyone know why I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue occur with other KMS clients?

It's recommended to go to Services on Windows > Found Software Protection (sppsvc), start or restart it to check this issue.

Sometimes, error code "0x80070005" is about insufficient user permission to activate Office. Please ensure you have run Command Prompt as administrator.

Please also make sure the user profile folder is not set as hidden.

Comment: What other KMS clients are there exactly?

Comment: Sorry, maybe it is not so clear. "KMS clients" means **other computers** which connect to the same KMS host to activate Office.